# Make a adjacency matrix in R

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph, tidyr, adjacency-matrix

I want to make an adjacency matrix from a dataframe (`mydata`) consisting several rows with following rule:

1. List all letters as a square matrix
2. Count and sum number of connection from `source` from rest of columns (`p1 p2 p3 p4 p5`) of corresponding rows. For example, `b` is connected with `a` (2 and 8 rows) 5 times.
3. If letter is not included in `source` , connection values should be zero.

The dataframe is:

```
mydf <- data.frame(p1=c('a','a','a','b','g','b','c','c','d'),
                               p2=c('b','c','d','c','d','e','d','e','e'),
                               p3=c('a','a','c','c','d','d','d','a','a'),
                               p4=c('a','a','b','c','c','e','d','a','b'),
                               p5=c('a','b','c','d','I','b','b','c','z'),
                               source=c('a','b','c','d','e','e','a','b','d'))
```

The adjacency matrix should be as following

```
        a b c d e g I z
      a 4 2 1 3 0 0 0 0
      b 5 1 3 0 1 0 0 0
      c 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 0
      d 1 2 3 2 1 0 0 1
      e 0 2 1 3 2 1 1 0
      g 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      I 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      z 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have hundreds of columns and thousands of rows. I would appreciate having any fastest way to do it in R

Answer (score 2):

In base R, we can use `table` :

```
vals <- unlist(mydf[-ncol(mydf)])
table(factor(rep(mydf$source, ncol(mydf) - 1), levels = unique(vals)), vals)

#  vals
#    a b c d e g I z
#  a 4 2 1 3 0 0 0 0
#  b 5 1 3 0 1 0 0 0
#  g 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  c 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 0
#  d 1 2 3 2 1 0 0 1
#  e 0 2 1 3 2 1 1 0
#  I 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  z 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

In `tidyverse` we can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -source) %>%
  count(source, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n) %>%
  complete(source = names(.)[-1]) %>%
  mutate_all(~replace_na(., 0))
```

Comment: Row name and column name do not come in the same order in the real data.

Comment: No. computation is correct, but order is not as desired.

Comment: What is the order that you desire? Can you include that in the example?

Comment: There is no specific order. What I need is the same sequence. In your solution above, a, b, c ,d, e, g, I, z are the column names, but row names has different sequence (a, b, g, c, d. ). Do you get my point?

Comment: @Discovery2020 You mean something like this? `table(factor(rep(mydf$source, ncol(mydf) - 1), levels = unique(vals)), factor(vals, levels = unique(vals)))` ? You can assign `levels` as per your choice.

Comment: No, it says "all arguments must have the same length"

Comment: Works fine for me on your sample data though. Does it work for you on sample data that you have shared?

Comment: It works in above data, but not real data. The real data have "NA". This could be problem. Any suggestion

Comment: I don't think `NA`s should matter because they are by default ignored in the calculation.  Can an entire column be `NA`? If I add 1 NA manually like `mydf$p1[1] <- NA` the above code still works.